# .htaccess Rewrite Rule Understanding Problems

Tags: .htaccess

**Site Structure**

```
/articles/Employment/Companies.php
/articles/Employment/Companies/.htaccess
/articles/Employment/Companies/index.php
```

---

**.htaccess file reads**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

So when you go to

> /articles/Employment/Companies/[company type]

It is displaying the `index.php` page.

---

**The Problem**

I'm trying to link to

> /articles/Employment/Companies.php

without the .php being displayed, however if I link to

> /articles/Employment/Companies

it is going to

> /articles/Employment/Companies/

---

**What i'm Ideally Looking For**

- Understand why I my site is adding the `/` when linking to `folder/hello`
- to strip out all `.php` so if you go to `/hello` it'll display `/hello.php` apart from in certain directories such as my current `.htaccess` file is located where `/this` or `/that` will display `/index.php`.

Comment: _“Understand why I my site is adding the / when linking to folder/hello”_ – that is due to [mod_dir’s `DirectorySlash` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). (Read the security note carefully, before disabling it.)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below, use from rewritecond with your existing rule what I am doing if the request is actually for php file which is not index.php then serve the extension less code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule !index.php$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This breaks my current rule to read the parent `.index.php` file, although there is a high chance I'm attempting to add it wrong, either eithin my code or the location. Could you add more clarity please?